# is there a difference in error output when placing error logging in the script vs in the cronjob itself?

Tags: bash, cron, cron-task

I am trying to figure out why the script runs using `./runmusic` but isnt launched from the cronjob. Where and why would be the best place to put the error reporting?

my script

```
pi@raspberrypi ~/Music $ cat runmusic 
#!/bin/bash    
exec >>omx_log_from_runmusic 2>&1
echo $(date)
DISPLAY=:0 

var=$(\ls songs/|shuf -n 1)
#omxplayer -o local /home/pi/Music/Bloodletting.mp3
omxplayer -o local "/home/pi/Music/songs/$var"
```

$crontab -l

```
* * * * * bash /home/pi/Music/runmusic > /tmp/setvals
```

I am not getting error reports from either of these files right now, although I am getting expected text output from the in-script logging. eg "Have a nice day :)" as the closing of omxplayer

Comment: The script is redirecting `stderr` to `stdout` which is redirected to `omx_log_from_runmusic`. You will find the error log in that file. The redirection in cron will be empty because the script has already redirected both `stderr` and `stdout` to a file. Redirection in cron is limited to redirecting `stdout` and `stdin` to a file together or separately. The script has far greater control because it can redirect to multiple destination as needed, such as one log for DB, another log for non-DB, etc.

Comment: Running interactive programs from `cron` is just crazy.

Comment: @triplee I didnt think this was an interactive program.... it just displays a notification. It doesnt need user input. Can you explain why running it like this is a bad idea?

Comment: Because there is no guarantee that an X server is running, that the display you are attempting to use exists and isn't being used by somebody else for something more important, etc.

Comment: Also [don't use `ls` in scripts](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs). A somewhat more robust replacement is `printf '%s\n' *` but even that is not enough for completely handling every possible file name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in comments, you're already redirecting all the output with `exec`, so there's nothing for `cron` to log. Assuming the permissions are reasonable, you should see your logging in `omx_log_from_runmusic`. You may want to specify an explicit path to the log file and ensure the user running `cron` has permission to write to it.

There's no need to create a subshell to run `date` and then echo the result, just run the command. It will be sent to the log with all the other output.

You would typically [set your script to executable](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_02_01.html) (`chmod +x mymusic`) and then call it directly from `cron`, as opposed to calling `bash` and passing the script name as an argument. Also related to cron, you're calling this every minute; are all your songs less than a minute long? If not, you may want to check to make sure `omxplayer` isn't still running before starting a new one.

And, [you should not be parsing the output from `ls`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) as you will run into problems as soon as you come across a file with whitespace in the name (see also [bash FAQ 50](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050).) You can use a [glob](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/glob) to get the file list into an array, and then use [`RANDOM`](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/randomvar.html) to [grab an element](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/026#line-110) out of the array.

```
#!/bin/bash
exec >> /full/path/to/omx_log_from_runmusic 2>&1
date
DISPLAY=:0 

if pgrep omxplayer
then
    exit
else
    files=(/home/pi/Music/songs/*)
    n=${#files[@]}
    omxplayer -o local "${files[RANDOM % n]}"
fi
```

Comment: If I could give you multiple upvotes for that I would.... that was considerably more detailed then I was expecting

Comment: I thought putting the omxplayer line in quotes would fix the whitespace issue? Does this not work?

Comment: No, because the output from `ls` in your script was passed to `shuf` as a string, and it doesn't recognize any difference between filename white space and syntactic white space.

Comment: I didnt think there was a difference between the two when everything was in quotes eg `mkdir "new folder"` works fine, but obviously `mkdir new folder` creates a folder with the name `new`.

Comment: Found the answer to my question in the bash FAQ you linked: This fails because of WordSplitting and because the single quotes inside the variable are literal, not syntactical. If $subject contains internal whitespace, it will be split at those points (when evaluating the command). I added the part in parentheses for completeness